# Grease & Thermal resistant cardboard for the foods industry?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I am on the lookout for, preferably, a cardboard (ish), that is both heat & grease resistant, for usage in microwave popcorn. As such, the material must be appropriate for direct contact with food.

The idea is that a tray is placed on the bottom of a box, that will shield the body from any grease that will go liquid when heated (microwaved). Obviously, the most widely available material, and the cheaper the better is the quest that I have undertaken, and I hope that you folks can point me in the right direction, as I can't quite afford professional help for this project, as it stands.

Comment: Hi Alamari, welcome to the site.  Can you give us a better sense of what type of temperature this material would need to withstand?  It may help for you to reframe this in terms of actual chemical properties rather than looking for a specific product, as "shopping recommendations" are technically off-topic on SE, and I think this would fall under that designation.

Comment: I don't want to answer your question, because it seems like it might be off-topic (and too narrow) as written. I will give you some advice, instead. Parchment paper has most of the properties that you want. It is paper embedded with silicone to provide heat resistance, a non-stick surface, and grease resistance.